# How to manually download, compile and install the tiff5 library on ubuntu 16.04 without root permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, tiff, libtiff

I need the tiff5 library, but I can not install it without the root permissions on ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone know the method please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to download the libtiff5 package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libtiff5/download, unpack it, place the libs from *usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu* directory somewhere (i.e. */home/user/custom_libs*), and add it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH by the command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/custom_libs/
```